# Ubuntu 16 or 18 on a new laptop (Dell Precision 7730)

Tags: 16.04, 18.04

I am coming back to linux after using mac for a while. I will use my laptop for work, doing a lot of demanding computations. The laptop ships with 16.04 and i am wondering if to do a clean install of 18.? or upgrade or stay on ubuntu 16.04.

I was looking for information before asking and have read that 18.04 and 18.10 lack in performance and stability. However these information seem to be old so I would greatly apreciate feedback from the community. If performance and stability are my main concerns, rather then fancy new features what version should i install?

Laptop is Dell Precision 7730, if anyone has first hand experience it would be greatly apreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I was on 16.04 and did a clean install on my ASUS laptop. When on 16.04 everything was running perfectly. With 18.04 there are a few problems, the sleep button is sort of hidden and sometimes computer freezes on restart. I did not revert to 16.04 and problems can be regarded as minor inconvenience. But if I knew I'd stay with 16.04 for now.

Comment: I might stay with 16.04 for now as well then, It is safer probably but will eventually cause me more work down the line as eventually i will want to upgrade, probably doing clean install.

Answer (score 0):

One of the most interesting things about Linux is how rarely things go sideways during upgrades such as from one LTS to another. This is no exception. Canonical dumped Unity and returned to GNOME (Ubuntu 18.04: Unity is gone, GNOME is back—and Ubuntu has never been better).

Unity was no Windows Vista. Some people liked Unity; I thought it was abysmal, but I was part of a small majority or very large plurality, since some were ‘on the fence’ about Unity. However, enough users complained about Unity and wanted GNOME back that Canonical listened to the market and put GNOME back in place (What’s New in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS “Bionic Beaver”, Available Now).

That’s the biggest — and the best — change. There are some others, but they are smaller improvements.

As soon as I have the time and opportunity, I will be upgrading my desktop and Laptop to a variant of Ubuntu 18.04, which is Ubuntu 18.04 Mate, which uses the Mate Desktop Environment instead of GNOME. That’s a personal preference. I don’t care for what GNOME’s become after GNOME 2.x

But do upgrade, it appears well worth it.

Comment: I will check out the difference between Unity and GNOME, i don't know it well enough yet to decide based on the difference. So much to learn and relearn coming back to linux...

Comment: Maybe you can select the answer for your question.